# In the following path what will be the easier path to ride a cycle?

Tags: kinematics, energy-conservation, friction, potential, drag

among the two paths what will be the easier path to ride cycle.
[image]

1. Riding it in an overhead bridge by pedaling when going up and letting cycle free when coming down.
2. riding it on a flat road and traveling the same displacement as in the first case.

consider driving in a practical situation i.e., with friction between wheels and road, with air drag, etc....

Comment: Hint: cycling is more popular in Holland than in Switzerland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path 2 is "better" in terms of both energy consumed and comfort.

1. Energy -- Work done by gravity is same in both cases, so let's ignore that. Looking at energy lost due to friction and air drag -- work done by friction and air drag depends on path and path 1 is longer. Plus, you'll need to brake when going downhill so as to not go too fast. Energy is wasted there. So, overall less energy is wasted in path 2.
2. Comfort -- Firstly, it is harder to go uphill than on a plain road; I know, I know, there's a downhill part as well on path 1, but then you need to maintain your speed using brakes. Secondly, path 2 is shorter so the time taken will be less if speed is same on both paths.